# How to add complex elements to an XML file using PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this piece of xml code that I can trying to add to a file on my pc:

```
<Connector port="9089" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"/>
```

The code I have been trying to use:

```
$config = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$config.Load($filePath)
$newElement = $config.CreateElement('Connector')
$newElement.InnerXml = 'port="9089" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"'
$config.Server.Service.AppendChild($newElement)
$config.Save($filePath)
```

But instead of the desired output above, the code adds the following to the xml file:

```
<Connector>
    port="9089" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
</Connector>
```

What changes could I make to the code to get the above output rather than the below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add *attributes*  so you have to use the `SetAttribute` method:

```
$config = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$config.Load($filePath)
$newElement = $config.CreateElement('Connector')
$newElement.SetAttribute("port", "9089")
$newElement.SetAttribute("protocol", "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol")
$config.Server.Service.AppendChild($newElement)
$config.Save($filePath)
```